# PHP Name Required for Form

Tags: php, string, forms, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am new to PHP and am trying to get this form to require certain fields to be filled in before allowing a submission. My email, phone number & zip all work, however my Name & does not. It took me a minute to realize why but now I do not know how to work around it.

On my field form I have Name inside the input box for the user to know what to put in that box, my PHP code only checks to see if there is anything A-z and a space possibly. Is there any way to check if it's not just "Name" in the field??? Thanks & hope that makes sense! :)

PHP CODE

```
$string_exp = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/';
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<label for="name"></label><input type="text" class="rounded" name="name" size="26"
value="Name" style="color:#775594;" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name'}"
onFocus="if(this.value=='Name'){this.value=''}" />
```

Comment: why to complicate?, simply check for empty to know it exists or not.  name can contain other characters also.

Comment: How do you check for, characters like, ā

Comment: Because if they do not fill out anything in the input it will continue to say "Name" therefore it will never be empty. But again I am new to php and am just using helpful advise I find. Thank you for future validations.

Comment: Then, you can check for empty and string "Name" and keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition:

```
$string_exp = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/';
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name) || $name == 'Name') {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

// for any unicode name, accent, umlauts .. etc:
$string_exp = '/^((\p{L}\p{M}*)|(\p{Cc})|(\p{P}\p{P}\p{N}.{3})|(\p{N})|(\p{Zs}))+$/ui';
```

[Read more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) about unicode regular expressions.

Comment: what about the other characters? like, é,è,à,ï.

Comment: Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: is there anyway to have it check the comment field to see if it says something other than "Comments" and if not then email it blank in that spot instead of it saying comment?? I am sure that's probably easy noob but I'm still learning. Or tying to anyways! :)

Comment: That is another question! but it should be like: `$comment = str_replace('Comment', '', $comment);`

Comment: If you have other questions please hit 'Ask Question', if I didn't answered correctly please tell so.

Comment: sorry. Nope, you answered my question & fixed my problem. Thank you